# Without using panda or numpy, how would I separate my data into even columns? Then sum up the last column

Tags: python, arrays, format

I am trying to align the year, model, and price. Then sum up the cost.

Saved as 'car.dat' data below without converting to csv or using panda and numpy.

> 2018,Alfa Romeo Stelvio Ti,$28,950
>
> 2022,Mercedes-Benz E350,$54,950
>
> 2022,Volvo XC90,49,900

**What I have so far using python idle shell 3.10.4:**

```
def main():
    file  = open('car.dat','r')
    content = file.readlines()
    #total =0
    #total =  all 3 rows.
    for line in content:
        print ('Year' 'Make/Model', 'Price')
        print ('-'*35)
        line = line.split('\n')
        print(line[0].replace(',',' ',2))
        #print ('Total'+ total)
main()
```

**Expected results below:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something similar to this:

```py
def main():
    total = 0
    print("Year".ljust(6), "Make/Model".ljust(10), "Price")
    print("-" * 35)
    with open('car.dat') as f:
        for line in f:
            year, make_model, price = line.split(",")
            print(year.ljust(6), make_model.ljust(10), price)
            total += int(price)
    print("-" * 35)
    print("total".rjust(16), str(total))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: the ljust and rjust methods just add spacing the front and back of strings, so that your strings are all lined up (since you can't use a normal CSV format or something like that)

Comment: Thank you.  I was able to also find some examples of ways to format.                                                                                                                              Old: '%d %d' % (1, 2)
New: '{} {}'.format(1, 2)
Output: 1 2
Old: '%10s' % ('test',)
New: '{:>10}'.format('test')
Output: test